# Recursion function - working

Tags: recursion

```
public class Temp{
static int add(int m,int n){
    if(m==0)
        return n+1;
    else if(n==0)
        return add(m-1,1);
    else
        return add(m-1,add(m,n-1));
}
public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(add(3,3));
}
}
```

I am not able to understand what this function is achieving. The output for (2,2) is 7 and for (3,3) is 61. I understand that the value of n decreases then value of m and then the base case is reached but how can I get the output without running the code for a given input?

Comment: A nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7sm9dzFtEI) explayining it.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: Actually the question was about the function and it is the same in any language. Hence I did not add the language tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Ackermann function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), an example of non-primitive recursive function.

What do you mean by *getting the output without running the code for a given input*?

If you wish to compute a given value, I suggest you use a `HashMap` as a cache so that you can reuse already computed values. Also, I think you'd better use `BigInteger` values if you use `m` values greater than 3.